# iPA creation without provisioning profile

Tags: ios

I just want to whether is it possible to create `iPA` without creating `provisioning profile` or developer account. I mean can be make an archive without selecting `provisioning profile`

Comment: Previously it was possible. Now you must have to select the developer account through wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. For exporting IPA files, in addition to: you have to have a paid account, you also would need to install the *distribution certificate* (Production) on your machine -or on the desired machine that should export- to be able to export IPA files.

The purpose of **provisioning profiles** is to let the devices to be authorized to run an your exported IPA file, they would be embedded in the app bundle. Logically, exporting an IPA file without containing any provisioning profile means that the IPA file won't work on any device, which it seems to be meaningless.

Comment: Thanks. Just tell me one more thing. Can i share IPA with tester without knowing his/her UDID. Though, I know the testflight ID of the same

Comment: @AdityaSrivastava If you would do it via itunesconnect (Testflight) no doubt you can! all you have to do is to invite the tester, if you know Testflight is an app which is similar to the appstore but in a testing environment. You don't have to know what is the tester device UDID... However, for uploading to itunesconnect, you have to have the distribution certificate :)